# Can't get captcha to work - can submit even with wrong answer

Tags: javascript, html, forms, captcha

I have a website I designed with a contact form on almost every page. The form has been getting hit with a lot of spam lately, so I want to add in a captcha - but Google's free reCaptcha sucks, so I want to use a better one.

I found this and want to use it:

http://jsfiddle.net/M5rvh/23/

HTML

```
<form action="php/contactus.php" method="post" name="contact_form" id="contact_form">
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  <br>
    <h5>Full Name *</h5>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="text" placeholder="John Doe" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" required />

    <h5>Association Name *</h5>
      <input type="text" name="association" class="text" placeholder="HOA Name" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" required />

    <h5>Email Address *</h5>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="text" placeholder="youremail@email.com" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" required />

    <h5>Phone Number *</h5>
      <input type="text" name="phone" class="text" placeholder="555-555-5555" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" required />

    <h5>Message *</h5>
      <textarea name="message" rows="6" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" required>Our HOA Concerns Are...</textarea>

    <h5 class="captchaclass">Captcha *</h5>
      <div class="submit">
        <input type="image" src="images/button-submit_s1.jpg" alt="Submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

var mathenticate = {
    bounds: {
        lower: 5,
        upper: 50
    },
    first: 0,
    second: 0,
    generate: function()
    {
        this.first = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.bounds.lower) + 1;
        this.second = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.bounds.upper) + 1;
    },
    show: function()
    {
        return this.first + ' + ' + this.second;
    },
    solve: function()
    {
        return this.first + this.second;
    }
};
mathenticate.generate();

var $auth = $('<input type="text" name="auth" required />');
$auth
    .attr('placeholder', mathenticate.show())
    .insertAfter('h5[class="captchaclass"]');

$('#contact_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if( $auth.val() != mathenticate.solve() )
    {
        alert('wrong answer!');
    }
});

})
</script>
```

I have tried to get this to work on this page (http://wmdouglas.org/apex.html) but it does not work right no matter what I try. The captcha shows up and is required to complete before submitting, but I can enter in the wrong answer and it still goes to my success page afterwards.

What is going on?

Comment: so, you added this question to ask whether or not to add the javascript code to the bottom of the page?

Comment: 1. You need to include jQuery before this code. 2. A JavaScript captcha is useless.

Comment: Musa, thank you. That got it to show, but why is a JavaScript captcha useless? Your comment is essentially useless as it left me with more questions than answers.

Comment: A bot will not do client side form validation

Comment: A bot will skip the form and post directly to contactus.php.

Comment: Kevin, do you think you could link me to some reading on how to stop this? I'm forced to learn this right now.

Comment: Well, I asked for help and some of you ended up spamming me even further. <sarcasm>Thanks.</sarcasm>

Comment: captcha verification need to be server-side like with google recaptcha http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: Google's recaptcha looks like garbage. Is there ANY other solution that is responsive and not coded wanky. Because Google's recaptcha is the worst piece of code they have ever written.